# How to differentiate Glue and Athena to use Apache Spark in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-serverless

On Nov-2022, Amazon Athena had started supporting Apache Spark.
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-athena-now-supports-apache-spark/?nc1=h_ls

I think it looks very similar to Glue.
How can we differentiate Athena and Glue when using serverless Spark on AWS ?

Thanks in advance.

I looked for information comparing the two on internet, but could not find it.
I would like to decide which to use depending on the situation, especially for streaming processes.

Comment: Have a look at these: https://ahana.io/answers/the-differences-between-aws-athena-and-aws-glue-ahana/ **AND** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde Unfortunately, they wouldn't help since they don't assume Athena had started supporting Spark. I would like to know how to differentiate Glue and Athena when using Spark.

Comment: I think as per the documentation, Athena provides an SQL-like interface to query S3 data with the help of Presto and Hive so basically it is a query engine. With the new addition of Spark support, the same workload can also be processed using Spark runtime so it's like Databricks notebooks. To run Athena queries, need an execution engine and now we have Spark as an option.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde Thanks. So Spark with Athena is for query, and Spark with Glue is for processing data, correct ?  Can't they be used for the opposite purpose ?